# Отправка картинки Андроид ява

Tags: java, android

Целый день гуглил, гулял по сайтам но не нашел норм примера отправки изображения на сервер. Больно часто хвалили библиотеку okHttp. если есть ссылки на учебники или уроки по отправки изображения на сервер или класс рабочий то поделитесь пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот хорошая библиотека. Там подробно все описано: https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request#perform-a-multipart-post-request